# FullCalendar select with resourceId

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using the FullCalendar 5.10.0 method "[Calendar::select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-select)" like this

```
calendar.select({new Date("2022-04-22T08:00:00"),  new Date("2022-04-22T18:00:00"), true, id});
```

The id variable is set to the id (B331) of the resource and the resource looks like this:

```
{id: 'B331', resourceId: 'B331', title: 'B331', occupancy: 8},
```

But keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating JSON inline, within the `{ curly brackets }`, you need to specify the property names:

So try:

```
calendarCB.select( { start: new Date("2022-04-26T08:00:00"), end: new Date("2022-04-28T18:00:00"), allDay: true, resourceId: id} );
```

perhaps easier to read if written like:

```
calendarCB.select(
    {
        start: new Date("2022-04-26T08:00:00"),
        end: new Date("2022-04-28T18:00:00"),
        allDay: true,
        resourceId: id
    }
);
```

where `id` is a variable you have available for the `resourceId` property.